# Echoing a PHP variable into an iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

My website revolves around the premise of users being able to edit, save, and post new posts. I recently implemented a wysiwyg that uses an iframe to format the text. I can submit these just fine and they work well, however, I'm having trouble editing them. I have another file that users can use to edit their work. Previously I used the following code to echo out the users' previous post:
 `<textarea><?php if($post)echo $post ?></textarea>`

 However this does not show the formatted text, instead it shows html tags, someting I don't want. Is there a way to output these variables into the iframe? Perhaps using something similar to a "value" parameter? Go to my website: awthr.com, for further context on what I'm talking about. In case it's not clear by my convoluted explanation.

Edit:
Maybe this will better explain what I'm going for:

```
<iframe value = "<?php $post ?>"></iframe>`
```

However this technique does not owrk`

Comment: I'm guessing this actually has nothing to do with the fact that it's in an iframe and more along the lines of not providing whatever wysiwyg library you're using with the format it is expecting. What one are you using btw?

Comment: @Mike I'm not using a wysiwyg library. I constructed one from scratch using javascript and html.

Comment: Start by going directly to the iframe `src` URL. Also, it may be something along the lines of html entity encoding in your `$post` variable. You *are* encoding the html entities, right? Also why not use one of the other 50,000 WYSIWYG javascript libraries that exist instead of coding your own?

Comment: @Mike I'm trying to do everything from scratch so i have a full understanding of what's going on